# Manipulating Native Windows Boarders with wxPython

Tags: python, windows-7, wxpython

In windows there is an icon and title in the upper left hand corner of the native boarder. I was wondering if it was possible to remove the icon and title, yet keep the icon and title that is displayed in the task bar using wxPython.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible because wxPython is wrapping the native widget. You might be able to simulate it what you want using a custom wx.Dialog by messing with the style flags you pass it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably end up doing that. I was seeing if this was possible, because it's a bit easier.